# Orthogonal Projection of a Point onto a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm dealing with an exercise that requires I find the orthogonal projection of a given point onto a given plane.

I don't want an answer directly for my exercise, I would instead like to understand the theory and apply it to my exercise.

So in that case, say we're given the point $P(1,2,3)$ and the plane $4x+5y+6z=7$

How does one find the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto the given plane?

Comment: Find a line $L$ through the point $(1,2,3)$ that is parallel to the normal vector to the plane (because the normal vector, by construction) is parallel to every vector in the plane. The intersection of $L$ with the plane is the orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 1):

An orthognal projection means the co-ordinate of the perpendicular from the point to the plane/line. In your case you are dropping a perpendicular from a point to a plane. Hence all you have to do is find the foot of the perpendicular drawn from (1,2,3) on the plane 4x+5y+6z=7.